# How to call facebook api to create a campaign in c#?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have got following curl code in documentation

```
curl \ 
-F 'name=My First Campaign' \  
-F 'campaign_group_status=PAUSED' \  
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \  
https://graph.facebook.com/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcampaign_groups
```

I don't know how can i create Campaign from here, I have got `<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>` and access token also. Please guide me.